# Django - download file without reloading the page

Tags: ajax, django, pdf, download

The flow looks like that:

1. user is filling the form
2. form is passed to the server by ajax
3. form is saved to db, then the pdf with the form data is created and saved in the app folder (probably a bad move here...)
4. ajax success causes the page to append a button 'Download' with value equal to current pdf's name so button 'Download' appears to the user
5. If user presses the button the very pdf that was just saved is gonna download.
6. Refreshing the page makes the button disappear.

I've got stuck on point 5. I have created another ajax (to avoid reloading the page) bound to the Download button. It correctly asks the server to look for the file, creates a django File object: `pdf_file = File(open(file_path, 'rb'))`
and creates a `HttpResponse` with file, and `content_type='application/pdf'` or `'application/download'`.
`response['Content-Disposition']` is `attachment`.

Then the ajax returns response - only it does not. Server raises no error but ajax error function is called.

I've read that downloading with ajax is not possible. Could you help me a bit to get it straight? If above snippets are not clear, I shall provide more code.
Python 3.5, Django 1.10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do like

```
window.location.href = "/url/to/downloadfile/"
```

in `javascript` after success of posting form. OR

```
#html
<button onclick="myfiledownload()">Download</download>
#javascript
function myfiledownload(){
    window.location.href = "/url/to/downloadfile/"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using ajax to download the file bind the button to a download link where the file may be hosted

https://www.mywebsite/download/?fileid=3247023

You should at least seperate your file in a media root
Note: in production you will have to use a cdn to host your static files

Comment: thank you, unfortunately I can accept only one answer